# Linux command or PHP function?

Tags: php, optimization, command

I'm trying to move a folder from its original path to another one. I found a couple of solutions to do this.

- `rename` PHP function: `rename($oldpath, $newpath);`
- Linux command directly from PHP: `exec("mv $oldpath $newpath");`

I suppose that both solutions do the same, but now I ask: Which should I use? And more important: **Why?**

I think that it's better to use PHP function to avoid interaction directly with OS, but I prefer a more elaborate opinion.

Comment: why? that's easy: webhosting services often block cmd executing functions.

Comment: And what happen if webhosting allow that kind of command? I suppose that they block them for security reasons, isn't it?

Comment: exactly. because cmds are not under control of open_basedir etc.

Comment: If you ever think you might run the code on another server (Windows) `rename()` would still work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

4 reasons to use the PHP command:

1. Like already mentioned - there is more chance to get permission problems with the Linux command.
2. `mv` only works on POSIX. If you ever encounter the need to run the code on Windows, it won't work.
3. The PHP command should be a bit faster, as it doesn't need to create a new process for the `mv` utility program.
4. This is the most important reason: with `exec`, you need to escape the paths manually. Does `$oldpath` and `$newpath` come from user input? If `$oldpath` is set to `--version;`, `$newpath` is now a standalone command, that can be, for example, `rm / -rf`.
   Sure, you can escape the paths, but with the PHP command you don't even have to worry about it.